# Not able to implement "real" facebook SSO on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

My goal:

- In my app I want users to be able to share stuff on theirs walls

Since facebook is built into iOS 6 directly, I want to utilise the login credentials
from the settings screen on iOS so that nobody needs to enter their username / password 
in my app.

I want that my users jump directly to the permissions dialog on facebook.

Somebody told me to utilise the defaults object to access those login credentials:

```
thzAppDelegate *delegate = (thzAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]
       && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]){
        [delegate facebook].accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        [delegate facebook].expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }
```

but this is NOT working: Even when I reset my simulator, add my username pass in the settings on iOS, I still get a LOGIN SCREEN in MY APP, but I expected only the permissions.

I added also the recommended lines in the delegate.m:

```
#pragma mark Facebook

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I DONT want to bother my users EVERY time with a login.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

Comment: thx but Im trying to avoid the complete change of my facebook code...tfollowing this tutorial it means I need to add the sdk framework but currently I work with include files from facebook

Comment: You should use the most recent framework, it surely makes things easier. Plus I don't know if you still can find documentation to old API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the facebook sdk code. You want to use something like this which utilizes the iOS 6 social framework.

```
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>


ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] autorelease];

 ACAccountType * facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSArray * permissions = @[@"publish_stream"];

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"whateverYourFacebookKeyIs",ACFacebookAppIdKey,permissions,ACFacebookPermissionsKey,ACFacebookAudienceFriends,ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted && error == nil) {
            /**
             * Now we can ask for more permissions
             **/
            NSArray *readPermissions = @[@"read_stream"];
            [dict setObject:readPermissions forKey: ACFacebookPermissionsKey];

            [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                if(granted && error == nil) {

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"error is: %@",[error description]);
                    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showFacebookAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error is: %@",[error description]);
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showFacebookAlert) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I cant see the event that is being called when the login and permissions request is finished, how do I implement it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you trying to figure out when the request is granted?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at `Accounts.framework` and `Social.frameworks` - the former provides you access to the user's social accounts through the `ACAccount` class, which you can then use to create `SLRequest` objects to run your social requests.

If you just want to share content on a wall, you might be able to bypass these steps completely and use the `SLComposeViewController`, which provides a modal view to share media via Facebook, Twitter, or Weibo. Apple have documentation and sample code available for all of these classes.